# How to execute many queries sequential in one click?

Tags: sql-server

I have some queries to be executed in live DB by my client. I want to find some way by which the person needs to run only one query (Action) which will run subsequent queries.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Stored Procedure with all the queries and then you can just call the stored procedure whenever you want to run the queries.